# What is the difference between setImageDrawable() and setDrawable() of ImageView

Tags: android, image, background, imageview, drawable

What is the difference between setImageDrawable() setDrawable() of ImageView. When to use which ?

Comment: There's no such method `setDrawable` for `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setImageDrawable` sets the image view with the drawable provided. You would use this to set a drawable in an imageView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

`setDrawable` doesn't exist in the ImageView class; so, you would never use it in the same context. It looks like it's going to be added to API 21, but that will be in the `RotateDrawable` class, which, wouldn't be used in the same context.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html